# One Facebook Pixel code in the page code, but two codes in Pixel Helper

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

I do not know why, but I have two Facebook pixel codes on my site. Facebook Pixel Helper shows that the first code is the one I inserted on my site and is responsible for collecting information about PageView. The second FB code has no ID, and the pixel code can not be displayed (because it does not exist). Below screen, how it looks:

[image]

Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses Facebook Pixel everywhere. So this might be from any Facebook widget, Like widget, Embedded Post or any other Facebook Component within your page.

This is normal and will not affect your Pixel.